# What method does Gnome shell use to gracefully close all windows belonging to an application?

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys

[image]

As shown in the screenshot (showing a modified gnome favorite bar, but still with stock functionality), when I right click an application with multiple windows open on the gnome favorites bar, I get the menu entry "Quit # windows". Clicking this closes each of the windows belonging to the application gracefully, giving the opportunity to save. Does anyone know what method gnome shell uses to accomplish this or how I could hook into this function with the command line?

I'm trying to build a hotkey that will mimic the behavior of the Command+Q hotkey on MacOS, and since the gnome favorites bar provides exactly the same functionality, I would like to use the pre-existing functionality (if at all possible) as I have been able to find or modify wmctrl and xdotool scripts and methods offered in previous threads.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55357/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-horvath-what-method-does-gnome-shell-use-to-gra).